# Error: Unexpected value 'DomSanitizer' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, istanbul

I try to test a DomSanitizer import.

But I still get this error:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'DomSanitizer' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.
```

And my test case looks like this:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, DomSanitizer, DossierFileService, ErrorProcessor, MatDialog, BrowserModule],
      declarations: [ DossierPersonalDataComponent ],
      providers: [{

        provide: DomSanitizer,
        useValue: {
          sanitize: () =>'safeString',
          bypassSecurityTrustHtml: () => 'safeString'
        }

      }]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

This are de dependencies in the ts file:

```
constructor(
    private dossierService: DossierService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private dossierFileService: DossierFileService,
    private errorProcessor: ErrorProcessor,
    private dialog: MatDialog
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `DomSanitizer` from `imports`. You should only import modules, not services. You should provide services. If `DossierFileService`, `ErrorProcessor` are services (I am not sure if MatDialog is or not), move them to providers.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, MatDialog, BrowserModule],
      declarations: [ DossierPersonalDataComponent ],
      providers: [{

        provide: DomSanitizer,
        useValue: {
          sanitize: () =>'safeString',
          bypassSecurityTrustHtml: () => 'safeString'
        }

      },
      DossierFileService,
      ErrorProcessor,
     ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```